# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 no grub loader selection

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have problem with dual boot on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. The hard disk, I am trying to use, was configured on another Lenovo G50 series, with Windows 10 as first OS. At that time, I managed to dual boot both OS without a problem.   Recently, the laptop was damged, therefore, I decided to try to use the Hard disk in another Laptop - Lenovo -thinkpad (Enhanced Experience 2.0) with boot mode: UEFI. The laptop started well direct to Windows 10, without Grub loader option for selection.

I did the following steps to install Ubuntu 16.04.
Step 1: Accessed BIOS setup (ThinkPad Setup) by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> Key.
For this laptop there is STARTUP tab: with the following options.
   **A**. UEFI/Legacy Boot     [Both- system will boot by following UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority setting, UEFI only and Legacy Only. I selected Legacy only so that I can boot from DVD and install Ubuntu, because without it boot on Windows 10.
  **B**.UEFI/Legacy Boot priory.

**Problem:**
During partition, for the last option it asked to create a partition for Reverse BIOS boot. I did that, however, After rebooting and returning to Both option in A, boot direct to MS Windows 10, without selection option.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 boots with UEFI bootloaders, and you installed Ubuntu in legacy mode, then switched to UEFI mode, so there is no grub bootloader for UEFI mode.  You added the necessary partition for a legacy boot on a gpt partitioned disk, but that was only to allow the legacy grub to install and boot.

Just reinstall in UEFI mode.  There must be a way to boot the install media in UEFI mode -- if not an obvious choice, then maybe setting a supervisor password on the UEFI settings (BIOS) may allow other choices.

Comment: You may have to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI. And may have to turn off UEFI Secure Boot also. And boot USB flash drive in UEFI mode and run Boot-Repair. In advanced options is uninstall/reinstall grub and it will convert install to UEFI boot. You may still need work arounds to boot Ubuntu, but should be able to boot from UEFI boot menu in UEFI mode.

Comment: hello ubfan1 and Vlad, thank you a lot, I managed to install and working.